# I need help on Reading and Writing files

Tags: java

I was tasked to write a program to write some websites on a text file and extract those who have the same top level domains and write it to a separate text file. This is my code:

```
FileWriter myWriter, comWriter, eduWriter, orgWriter, netWriter;
    File newFile = new File("URL.txt");
    newFile.createNewFile();

    try {
        myWriter = new FileWriter("URL.txt");
        myWriter.write("""
                yahoo.com
                google.com
                usl.edu
                battle.net
                CSU.edu
                shopee.com
                xyz.org
                spup.edu
                slideshare.net
                php.net""");
        myWriter.close();
        System.out.println("Successfully wrote to the file!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Program didn't write");
    }

    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(newFile);

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

            String line = scanner.nextLine();

            if (line.endsWith(".com")) {
                comWriter = new FileWriter("com.txt");
                comWriter.write(line);
                comWriter.close();
            }
            if (line.endsWith(".edu")) {
                eduWriter = new FileWriter("edu.txt");
                eduWriter.write(line);
                eduWriter.close();
            }
            if (line.endsWith(".net")) {
                netWriter = new FileWriter("net.txt");
                netWriter.write(line);
                netWriter.close();
            }
            if (line.endsWith(".org")) {
                orgWriter = new FileWriter("org.txt");
                orgWriter.write(line);
                orgWriter.close();
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error occurred");
    }
```

My program creates new txt files. However, it only prints one line. For example, in my com.txt file it only prints "shopee.com"

Is there something that I'm missing? Improvements? Or wrongs maybe? I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: read the file, split the string with delimiter `.` and check with if condition, then write again to another file.

Comment: You might want to check out documentation of [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class and try using some of the methods.

Comment: Just to be picky, facebook.com and yahoo.com are different domains. I think you mean they have the same _top-level domain_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are opening the files for writing always truncates the output files. If you call the `FileWriter` constructor with just the file name, then that file will be opened for writing and truncated.

In order to append to the file, you should use the constructor that takes a boolean argument that specifies whether you want to append or not:

```
comWriter = new FileWriter("com.txt", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Files.write` method from NIO.2 instead of `FileWriter`:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
lines.add("yahoo.com");
lines.add("google.com");

Files.write(Paths.get("URL.txt"), lines);
```

Or

```
Files.write(Paths.get("URL.txt"), lines, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

if you want to append to existing file.

Optionally you can create a list of lines like this:

```
List<String> lines = List.of("yahoo.com", "google.com");
```

The file is closed when all lines have been written automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways this sort of thing can be done. Here is one example using Java's **[NIO](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/index.html)**:

**Creating the URL List file:**

```
List<String> urlList = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"yahoo.com", "google.com", "usl.edu",
                       "battle.net", "CSU.edu", "shopee.com", "xyz.org", "spup.edu",
                       "slideshare.net", "php.net"});
    
try {
    java.nio.file.Files.write(java.nio.file.Paths.get("URL.txt"), 
                              urlList, java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println("Successfully created the URL.txt file!");
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println("Error creating the URL.txt file!" + 
                       System.lineSeparator() + ex.getMessage());
}
```

**Reading the URL List file and creating [Top-Level Domain](https://www.howtogeek.com/126670/the-difference-between-.com-.net-.org-and-why-were-about-to-see-many-more-top-level-domains/) (TLD) files:**

```
/* 
  Creates Top-Level Domain (TLD) files that will store respective Domain Name Strings.

  Returns a comma (,) delimited string containing the Number of TLD files created and
  the number of Domain Name Strings added to the various TLD files created (in that
  order).

  Output to console can be commented out or removed from this method.

  If the supplied source path does not exist then an 'IllegalArgumentexception' is
  thrown.

  If the supplied destination path does not exist then there will be an attempt to
  create it. 
*/
public static String createTopLevelFiles(String sourcePath, String destinationPath) {
    // Does Source file exist? Throw exception if not.
    sourcePath = sourcePath.replace("\\\\",File.separator).replace("\\",File.separator);
    if (!java.nio.file.Files.exists(java.nio.file.Paths.get(sourcePath))) {
        // No...
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("createTopLevelFiles() Method Error!"
                + "Source file can not be found! (" + sourcePath + ")");
    }

    // Read Source file domains content into a List Interface Oject:
    // =============================================================
    List<String> urlList = null;
    try {
        java.nio.file.Path path = java.nio.file.Paths.get(sourcePath);
        urlList = java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(path, java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        if (urlList == null || urlList.isEmpty()) {
            System.err.println("createTopLevelFiles() Method Warning! No Domains "
                             + "available within URL List source file!");
            return null;  // Exit with null due to failure;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("createTopLevelFiles() Method Error!"
                         + System.lineSeparator() + ex.getMessage());
        return null;  // Exit with null due to failure;
    }
    
    // =============================================================

    // Check Destination Path - Create it if it doesn't already exist:
    // =============================================================
    destinationPath = destinationPath.replace("\\\\",File.separator).replace("\\",File.separator);
    java.nio.file.Path destPath = java.nio.file.Paths.get(destinationPath);
    if (!java.nio.file.Files.exists(destPath)) {
        try {
            // Creating the new directory because it doesn't exist in local system.
            Files.createDirectories(destPath);
            // System.out.println("Destination Directory Successfully Created!");
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Problem Occured While Creating The Destination "
                             + "Directory!" + System.lineSeparator() + ex.getMessage());
            return null;  // Exit with null due to failure;
        }
    }
    // =============================================================
    
    // Create the Top-Level Domain files:
    // =============================================================
    int fileCount = 0; // Keep count of TLD file creations.
    int failCount = 0; // Keep count of Saved Domain Name failures.
    for (String domain : urlList) {
        String fileName = domain.substring(domain.lastIndexOf(".") + 1) + ".txt";
        String filePath = new StringBuilder(destinationPath)
                              .append(File.separator).append(fileName)
                              .toString().replace("\\\\",File.separator)
                              .replace("\\",File.separator);
        try {
            java.nio.file.Path fPath = java.nio.file.Paths.get(filePath);
            // If the file doesn't already exist then create it...
            if (!java.nio.file.Files.exists(fPath)) {
                java.nio.file.Files.createFile(fPath);
                System.out.println("Successfully created the \"" + 
                        filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1) 
                        + "\" TLD file!");
                fileCount++;
            }
            // Is the domain name already in file? if so ignore it.
            List<String> tmpList = null;
            tmpList = java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(fPath, java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            if (tmpList.contains(domain)) {
                tmpList.clear();
                failCount++;
                continue;
            }
            // Append the domain name String to file...
            java.nio.file.Files.write(fPath, (domain + System.lineSeparator()).getBytes(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8), 
                                      java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
            System.out.println("Successfully added the \"" + domain + "\" domain name to the '" 
                    + filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1) 
                    + "' TLD file!");
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            failCount++;
            System.err.println("WARNING - Error creating the " + 
                    filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1) + 
                    " file! | " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    // =============================================================
    
    // Failure results (delete this code if you like).
    // =============================================================
    if (failCount > 0) {
        System.err.println(failCount + " out of " + urlList.size() + 
                           " domain names failed to be added!");
        System.err.println("This could be due to the fact that the domain");
        System.err.println("name is already stored or, one or more domain"); 
        System.err.println("names were found to be invalid.");
    }
    // =============================================================
    
    /* Return the total number of TLD files created and
       the total number of domain names added to these 
       various TLD files.      */
    return new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(fileCount)).append(", ")
            .append(String.valueOf((urlList.size() - failCount))).toString();
}
```

The method above will automatically create the destination path (directory path) within the local file system if it doesn't already exist and it automatically determines the file names required to create into that destination path based on the TLD domain name attached to each domain name string. Domain name strings are appended to their respective file once that file is created. If a Domain Name is already contained within a TLD file then that name is ignored and 1 is added to the failure count.

Read all comments in code.

**Usage Example:**

```
String result = createTopLevelFiles("URL.txt", "D:\\Top-Level_Domains");
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Result is:  " + result);
```

**Console output example:**

```
Successfully created the "com.txt" TLD file!
Successfully added the "yahoo.com" domain name to the 'com.txt' TLD file!
Successfully added the "google.com" domain name to the 'com.txt' TLD file!
Successfully created the "edu.txt" TLD file!
Successfully added the "usl.edu" domain name to the 'edu.txt' TLD file!
Successfully created the "net.txt" TLD file!
Successfully added the "battle.net" domain name to the 'net.txt' TLD file!
Successfully added the "CSU.edu" domain name to the 'edu.txt' TLD file!
Successfully added the "shopee.com" domain name to the 'com.txt' TLD file!
Successfully created the "org.txt" TLD file!
Successfully added the "xyz.org" domain name to the 'org.txt' TLD file!
Successfully added the "spup.edu" domain name to the 'edu.txt' TLD file!
Successfully added the "slideshare.net" domain name to the 'net.txt' TLD file!
Successfully added the "php.net" domain name to the 'net.txt' TLD file!

Result is: 4, 10
```

4 TLD files created in destination path and 10 domain names were added to those files.